# Getting a new harddrive, and want to use Ubuntu. Will it work on my emachine?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, software-recommendation

My PC hard-drive blew up and I am getting a Toshiba HD to replace that one. Is this going to be way over my head? I have read up on Ubuntu, and I really like what I have seen. I was going to use my Microsoft win 7 key to get a replacement CD to upload on this one, but looking into it Microsoft has one jump thru way to many hoops, and I just dont want to bother with them any longer. My pc is an emachine. Just putting the new HD in the case, so, hoping this is something feasible, and not just another one of my wacky ideas :/

Comment: What I'm gathering from your question is that you need to put a new hard drive in your computer and want to simply install Ubuntu. As far as I know, you should be able to install Ubuntu just fine, so long as you get the right version for your CPU. You can't install 64 bit Ubuntu on a machine with a 32 bit CPU, but you can run 32 bit Ubuntu on a 64 bit CPU (although you'll get better performance if you run the 64 bit version.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: @DavidFoerster No, I think it's fine. Upvotes are always appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Converted from a comment as per David Foerster's request and multiple upvotes.

---

What I'm gathering from your question is that you need to put a new hard drive in your computer and want to simply install Ubuntu.

As far as I know, you should be able to install Ubuntu just fine, so long as you get the right version for your CPU.

You can't install 64 bit Ubuntu on a machine with a 32 bit CPU, but you can run 32 bit Ubuntu on a 64 bit CPU (although you'll get better performance if you run the 64 bit version.)

For further explanation and alternatives refer to [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](/q/206407).